# Bandwidth of combined switch and router

Tags: networking, router, nas, bandwidth, switch

I want to build a HTPC (Home Theater PC) connected to a NAS (Network Access Storage) server where all the media will be.

My HTPC and NAS server will be connected to a Gigabit Ethernet switch, and this switch will be connected to a Fast Ethernet router which provides internet from the ISP.

**Will the connection between the HTPC and the NAS have a Gigabit (1000Mb) or Fast (100Mb) bandwidth?**

If I'm not wrong:

- When the HTPC will try to access the NAS server, it will do it
  directly through the switch, and therefore with Gigabit Ethernet
  connection (1000Mb of bandwidth).
- However, when the HTPC will try to access the internet (or other
  device connected to the router), it will do it through the switch and
  then the router, and therefore with Fast Ethernet connection (100Mb
  of bandwidth).
- When someone will try to access the NAS from, lets say, the Wifi
  provided by the router, it will do it through router then switch, and
  therefore at a bandwidth determined by the Wifi protocol (normally less than      ethernet).

**Is all this correct?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're not doing anything fancy and your HTPC and NAS are in the same subnet (which will be case if you're just using one regular consumer router), yes, the HTPC to NAS connection will be gigabit.

Yes, HTPC to any other device not directly connected to the switch will be 100 Mbit since it needs to traverse the link connected to the router, which is 100 Mbit.

Someone connecting over WiFi to the router will connect to the NAS at 100 Mbit max, but likely, as you already mentioned, be limited by WiFi speeds depending on connection quality.

Comment: NB: Modern wireless N can do 210Mb and closer to 350 on AC. But your router isnt up to that spec if its only got FE ;)